# cartopy: higher resolution for great circle distance line

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am trying to plot a great circle distance between two points. I have found an in the cartopy docs (introductory_examples/01.great_circle.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())

ax.set_global()

ax.coastlines()

plt.plot([-0.08, 132], [51.53, 43.17], color='red',      transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.plot([-0.08, 132], [51.53, 43.17], color='blue', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.show()
```

which makes the following image:

[image: great circle example]

The thing is, in my own work, the two points are much closer together, and in a different projection (though I think that isn't important here). If I change this code to be a line in a smaller area, like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())

ax.set_extent([-5, 55, 40, 55])

ax.coastlines()

plt.plot([-0.08, 50], [51.53, 43.17], color='red',      transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.plot([-0.08, 50], [51.53, 43.17], color='blue', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.show()
```

This makes the following image:

[image: shorter line]

The red great circle line in this case looks crappy and looks like it is due to being too low resolution. How do I increase the number of points making up the great circle line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This problem is due to the hard-coded threshold in the projection. Currently this is not a user controllable parameter, but you can work around that by defining your own sub-class:

```
class LowerThresholdRobinson(ccrs.Robinson):

    @property
    def threshold(self):
        return 1e3
```

If you use `LowerThresholdRobinson()` instead of `ccrs.Robinson()` when defining the axes this should eliminate the problem.

Comment: I get an error when trying this work-around. `ValueError: Image size of 319440347x319385677 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction` using Python 3.7.2 and Cartopy 0.17.0. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried using this with PlateCarree - fiddling with the threshold value either makes the "steppiness" worse, or the line just becomes a straight line

Comment: The default threshold for PlateCarree is much smaller at 0.5 for a global plot. Did you try values smaller than 0.5?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60724892/6764310

Comment: I could not get this working, but KiwiKilian's link worked a treat