# Plot Fine Grained Geodesic with Cartopy

Tags: python-3.x, cartopy

The following code (copied from [here](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/matplotlib/intro.html#adding-data-to-the-map)) produces a nicely looking geodesic between NYC and New Delhi. Upon close inspection, the geodesic does not look smooth. How can I make it smooth looking?

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ny_lon, ny_lat = -75, 43
delhi_lon, delhi_lat = 77.23, 28.61

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.stock_img()

plt.plot([ny_lon, delhi_lon], [ny_lat, delhi_lat],
         linewidth=2, marker='o', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: broken geodesic]

Comment: Any comment on my answer?

Comment: @swatchai Fantastic, that was exactly what I wanted! I just missed your post somehow. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set a finer threshold of the line segments along the plotted geodesic line. Here is the relevant lines of code to do so.

```
plateCr = ccrs.PlateCarree()
# print(plateCr._threshold) # original threshold=0.5
plateCr._threshold = plateCr._threshold/10.  #set finer threshold
ax = plt.axes(projection=plateCr)
```

Replace the line:

```
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

with the proposed code above. The result plot should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Current versions of cartopy do not require that you access the private member `_threshold`; use the property `threshold` instead